# Change Spinner Without Using Custom View

Tags: android

i was just wondering if there is a way to achieve this spinner in this image without using custom view or adapter. My spinner isnt dynamic so I added the months using

```
android:entries="@array/months"
```

thus, i dont need any adapter. So is it possible not to make one and produce this output? Anyone could help me with this? It will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.[image: spnr]

Here is my spinner in xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnr_months"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:entries="@array/months"/>
```

Comment: Red and yellow is other layout ??

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ dont mind it sir, its a graph .. What i was referring is the spinner with "January". How am i able to achieve it without using custom views? Thanks

Comment: do you want just a spinner with the triangle at right side?

Comment: @AmanGrover yes, a white spinner and triangle without using custom view. Thanks

Comment: have you tried using AppCompatSpinner? just add this style to your spinner: `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"`

Comment: @AmanGrover doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html).Just provide the layout for the dropdown view.The triangle image in the spinner is achieved using the spinner style.